# TypeError: f is not a function

Tags: eosjs

I'm trying out the eosjs official documentation, but can't make any RPC calls.
This is how I've initialized everything:

```
const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } = require('eosjs');
const { fetch } = require('node-fetch');
const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80', { fetch });

rpc.get_info().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

I get an error saying:

```
{ TypeError: f is not a function
    at JsonRpc.<anonymous> (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:99:46)
    at step (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
    at Object.next (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53)
    at /home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:11:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:7:12)
    at JsonRpc.fetch (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:92:16)
    at JsonRpc.<anonymous> (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:208:55)
    at step (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
    at Object.next (/home/krtk6160/Desktop/konnectSense/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53) isFetchError: true }
```

I've tried with eosjs versions 20.0.0, 20.0.0beta3, 20.0.0beta1 but the error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was how I was importing the fetch module.
I was able to fix the issue by importing the fetch module in the following way:

`const fetch = require('fetch')`

Comment: Use `'node-fetch'` when fetching from the server (node) and `'fetch'` when fetching from the client.